# C Redirect the output from other program to the father

Tags: c, exec, dup2

I'm writting a programming using exec, pipes and forks

My main program create the pipe, forks. The father ask a number by keyboard, and send it to another program called "Factorial" (the son use exec). The fatorial receive the number, calculate the fatorial and send the result back to the main program ... but the result its always -1.

Main program

```
    int pipeFromProgram[2], pipeToProgram[2],numero_keyboard= 0, num_factorial=-1
  // Forks and Pipes ..
  pipeFromProgram = createPipe();;
  pipeToProgram = createPipe();
  x = createSon();

 if(x == 0) {  //Father
    numero_teclado = escolherNumero();
    close(pipeToProgram[0]);
    write(pipeToProgram[1],&numero_teclado, BUFFER);   //The other program receives correctly the number.
    close(pipeToProgram[1]);


            close(pipeFromProgram[1]);      
    read(pipeFromProgram[0], &num_factorial,BUFFER);   //Receive the result
    printf("PIPE %d\n",num_factorial);   //The result its always -1 (declared as)
    close(pipeFromProgram[0]);  

    wait(NULL);
  }else{ 
        close(pipeToProgram[1]);        
    dup2(pipeToProgram[0], 0); 
    dup2(pipeFromProgram[1],1);
    close(pipeToProgram[0]);                
    execlp("./factorial", "factorial", NULL);
    perror("Exec error\n");
}
```

Fatorial.c

```
 int main(void){
   int i , result = 1, num = 1;
   read(0,&num,sizeof(int));
   printf("Numero recebido %d\n\n", num);   //Number its correct
   for (i = 1; i <= num; i++){
    result = result * i;  //Factorial ...
   }
   write(1,&result,sizeof(int));   //also tried the &result+1
   return 0;
 }
```

Here is and exemple of output:
       Number to calculate: 4

---

```
   1
   2
   6
   24   /So fatorial.c receive the number correctly and calculate it
```

---

```
   PIPE: -1
```

As you can see the result its always -1 ( value declared) .. So i guess the problem its the write in fatorial.  Am i wrong?

### ps:

```
   void cratePipe(int p[2]){
     int i; 
    if(pipe(p) == -1){
      perror("Pipe failed");
     }
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you set the `stdout` of the child process to be `p[1]`? It would help if you showed a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, what `createPipe` does. Also,suggest you use more meaningful and more distinct variable names than `p` and `p1` - quite confusing as it is as they are so similar.

Comment: ok .. give me 1 minute

Comment: If you are updating the question, please be sure to answer the first part of the previous comment as that is the key. Are you duping `p[1]` to be the `stdout` of the child process?

Comment: My mistake. yes i'm duping p[1] to be the stdout of the child process

Comment: Where? Either you have not shown that code or I'm just not seeing it. And your `createPipe` does not make sense. It is defined to take a parameter yet your code calls it with no parameter. Please don't make up the code as you go. That is not a productive use of anyone's time to have to go back and forth. Please post the *exact* and *complete* code. Make sure you compile and run exactly what you show to confirm it does compile and does behave as you have described.

Comment: The code itself for the father is missing partly, can you update that, too?

Comment: Nevermind.. i'm not doing the dup to the stdout ... i guess i could resolve the problema with just 1 dup2 ... So u are saying that i need to dup2(p[1],1) on father when i receive the number from factorial?

Comment: No, I'm saying you need to do the dup before calling `exec`. Just as you are already doing for `stdin`. Note, if you do it properly, then none of your child `printf` statements will appear as they will be written to the pipe. So, in fact, you should not have any debug `printf` calls in your factorial program. Otherwise they will confuse the father process which only expects the factorial result to come back and not debug strings.

Comment: Code update... now i dup the stdout , the fatorial no longer has prints.  But now my output its the PIPE : number by keyboard + 1 ( if i introduce 6 the result its 7 ) ... so i guess now my problem its just the algorithm to calculate the fatorial since the pipes are working and i can fix it

Comment: The factorial code as shown still has a `printf` immediately after the `read` call.

Comment: I just have to reajust a little bit a code (change the factorial ) ... and now its working. The dup2 to the stdout i said, made the difference and i was just a little reajust on factorial. Thank you!